# Can Web2py be made to serve images from a directory outside of the application directory?

Tags: web2py

I am writing a small app to tag 15+ years worth of photos. Can Web2py be made to serve files (particularly .jpeg images) from a directory outside of the application directory? Maybe something similar to an IIS virtual directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
def image(): # http://.../image/where/ever/it/is.jpeg
    filename = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'/'.join(request.args))
    return response.stream(open(filename,'rb'))
```

You may want to do some validation and set the content-type manually.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to stream the images. Yes, I would want to set the content-type, but still, this is a whole lot easier than when I've had to do the same thing in .JSP (Java) and .ASPX (C#). And if this is the Massimo I think it is... Thank you for Web2py (http://web2py.com/) and congratulations on your recent interview on FLOSS weekly (http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/188). I wouldn't have attempted this Hot-or-Not inspired, get my entire family of 7 involved in tagging 15 years of images app, without Web2py.

Answer (score 1):

Which platform are you using?  If you are on Linux, the easiest solution would be to create a symbolic link to your target directory.  For example:

```
~$ ln -s /your/photos /home/www-data/web2py/applications/photoapp/static/images
```

If you use Windows, you can do the same thing using the command line:

```
C:\mklink /D C:\www\web2py\applications\static\images C:\Users\MyPhotos\
```

This [howtogeek.com article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) provides a good overview of how to make a symbolic link in Windows.

Comment: Yes. I suppose I could, this will be on Linux. Though, in the end, I may end up having to resize the images and streaming them.